# How to extract the values of dynamically created table cells from a table on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am dynamically creating a table and each row has a button. On click of the button OI want to extract that row's cell values.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="alterationsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Problem/Event</th>
          <th>Discuss</th>
          <th>Outcome Modification</th>
          <th>Add/Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="alterationsTablebody">
        <tr>
            <!-- Place for training alterations/notes details -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>                
</table>
```

js to create:

```
var html = '';
            
html += "<tr><td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' id='date' name='date' class='alterationsDetailDate' value='" + todayDate + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' id='0' name='problem' class='alterationsDetail maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='text-align : center; width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='checkbox' id='0' name='discuss' class='form-check-input alterationsDetail' value=''></td>";         
html += "<td><input type='text' id='0' name='outcome' class='alterationsDetail maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='button' id='addAltBtn' name='addAltBtn' class='alterationsAdd btn-info' value='Add'></td></tr>";
```

$(html).appendTo($("#alterationsTablebody"));

js to extract:

```
$('#alterationsTable tbody').on( 'click', '#addAltBtn', function () {
    alert("here");

    alert($(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:eq(1)').text());//Returns blank

    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),// Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td");// Finds all children <td> elements

    $.each($tds, function() { // Visits every single <td> element
        alert($(this).val()); // Returns blank
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't reuse IDs! Bind to the new row's button with `input[type=button]` or `input[name="addAltBtn"]` or `input.alterationsAdd`. Also every time you add a new row, you're binding the event handler to the click event again for each existing element, meaning it will call it another time for each new row. So if you have 3 rows, the first one will call the handler 3 times! Either `.unbind()` first, or better yet, only bind to the new row's input button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are trying to access value from td element but actual value will be stored in input element inside td element. Check the code snippet.

```js
var html = '';
var todayDate = new Date();  

html += "<tr><td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' id='date' name='date' class='alterationsDetailDate' value='" + todayDate + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' id='0' name='problem' class='alterationsDetail maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='text-align : center; width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='checkbox' id='0' name='discuss' class='form-check-input alterationsDetail' value=''></td>";         
html += "<td><input type='text' id='0' name='outcome' class='alterationsDetail maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='button' id='addAltBtn' name='addAltBtn' class='alterationsAdd btn-info' value='Add'></td></tr>";

let tableBodyElement=document.getElementById("alterationsTablebody");

$(html).appendTo($("#alterationsTablebody"));


$('#alterationsTable tbody').on( 'click', '#addAltBtn', function () {
    alert("here");  
alert($(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:eq(1)').children(':first').val());
    
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),// Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td");// Finds all children <td> elements

    $.each($tds,function() { // Visits every single <td> element
       if($(this).children(':first').prop('type')=="checkbox"){// checking for checkbox 
         alert($(this).children(':first').prop('checked'))
       }
       else{
        alert($(this).children(':first').val()); // return value
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="alterationsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Problem/Event</th>
          <th>Discuss</th>
          <th>Outcome Modification</th>
          <th>Add/Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody id="alterationsTablebody">
        <tr>
            <!-- Place for training alterations/notes details -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>                
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can up with based on Abhilash's answer:

js to create:

```
var html = '';

html += "<tr><td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='text' id='id' name='id' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' id='date' name='date' value='" + todayDate + "'></td>";
html += "<td><input type='text' id='problem' name='problem' class='maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='text-align : center; width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='checkbox' id='discuss' name='discuss' class='form-check-input' value=''></td>";         
html += "<td><input type='text' id='outcome' name='outcome' class='maxWidth' value=''></td>";
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='button' id='addAltBtn' name='addAltBtn' class='btn-info' value='Add'></td></tr>";

$(html).appendTo($("#alterationsTablebody"));
```

js to extract:

```
var date = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[id="date"]').val();
var problem = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[id="problem"]').val();

if ($(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[id="discuss"]').is(':checked')){
    discuss = "Y";
}else{
    discuss = "N";
}

var outcome = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[id="outcome"]').val();
```